# Change video player stream aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, html, video-streaming, aspect-ratio

I have a html video player element `<video/>`, and a m3u8 stream.
It is possible to change the aspect ratio from 4:3 to 16:9 of the stream 
depending on the stream resolution ?!

Answer (score 0):

The onloadedmetadata event will fire when the videoWidth and videoHeight are known (as well as duration etc), you can then use that to adjust the width/height of the display element